# Modifying Serial ID to include numbers based on data in another cell [Excel 2010]

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create new serial IDs based on the data in two cells in MS Excel 2010.

The first cell contains the current serial ID e.g. A^B
The second cell contains a quantity e.g. 4

The result I want to produce in the third cell should identify the number in the second cell and concatenate the value sequentially in the third cell i.e the out of the first and second cell identified in the example above should be

A^B^1
A^B^2
A^B^3
A^B^4 (all in different cells in a column)

I have 500 serial numbers with a varying amount of quantities each therefore, I would like to request help with a routine or way which can help me create the third cell quickly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You say the third cell shoudl be concatenated but then go on to say is should be in different cells....  If you want them concatenated then a UDF should be fairly straight forward..

something like:

```
Function myfunction(Ftext As String, Ntimes As Integer) As String

    Dim chk As Integer
    chk = 1

    Do While chk <= Ntimes
        myfunction = myfunction & Ftext & chk & " "
        chk = chk + 1
    Loop

    myfunction = Trim(myfunction)

End Function
```

You would just use this in the worksheet like any other function

```
=myfunction(cell1,cell2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the function. I tried it but it doesn't produce any result. Just shows #VALUE in the third column when it try to invoke this function.

Comment: To clarify about my statement, I meant that cell 1 and 2 should concatenate serially but the result should be shown in the third column. For example if we have the following input:  

Column 1, Column 2  
A_12^2, 3  
A_37^B, 4  
Based on this input, column 3 output should be  
Column 3  
A_12^2^1  
A_12^2^2  
A_12^2^3  
A_37^B^1  
A_37^B^2  
A_37^B^3  
A_37^B^4

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using a macro to fill in all the cells:

```
Sub CreateSerialNumbers()

    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

    With Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change to your sheet name
        For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Assume we start in row 2 and work to the bottom of the sheet
            For j = 1 To .Cells(i, 2).Value
                .Cells(i, j + 2).Value = .Cells(i, 1).Value & "^" & j
            Next j
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

This assumes your data starts in row 2, and that the serials are in column A and the numbers are in column B.

Comment: Thank you for the code. I have added it but it gives me a type mismatch error even though I have checked the types of both inputs.

Comment: I'd guess you have non-numerical data in your second column, the one with the numbers.  Use the immediate window to find the the value of i when the error occurs.  This will tell you the row with the "bad" data.